# How to have two domains with dedicated ip addresses and ssl certificates point to the same directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cpanel, whm

In CPanel how would you configure two different accounts with two different IP addresses and a ssl certificate for each account to point to the same directory. The accounts are on same server / whm installation. Basically what I am looking for is if you access site1.com or site2.com you see the exact same website, just under a different domain name, and the ssl certificates need to work for each. (Don't worry about the SEO implications, it is one application controlling the site and will display totally different info based on the address being accessed)

Answer (score 0):

u can put in your dns server a directive redirection to first site using the same ssl certificate..or maybe hide/lock site in url

Comment: Can you please explain? I want each site to be accessible through each sites domain, on different IP addresses, using each ssl certificates.

Comment: u says one certificate to each domain?

Comment: DocumentRoot "/home/site1/"
ServerName site1.com:443
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
TransferLog "/var/log/httpd/access_log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/site1/site1.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/site1/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/site1/EssentialSSLCA_2.crt

Comment: DocumentRoot "/home/site1/"
ServerName site2.com:443
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
TransferLog "/var/log/httpd/access_log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/site2/site2.com.crt2
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/site2/privkey.pem2
SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/site2/EssentialSSLCA_2.crt2